# MediaElement.js going white in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, mediaelement.js

I am testing MediaElement.js playing in IE6. It starts off working fine, the video is there, playing, within the Flash player. However, when I mouse over the video, it disappears (goes completely white). If I refresh the browser with the mouse where the video lands, and click into it, I can then interact with the controls a bit, but the full screen button causes it to go white again.

**EDIT:**

A couple other observations:

- The audio continues to play even though the video is white
- If I select the video area, I can get a hilight the shape of the video
- Right clicking the white video region does not indicate a Flash component is present.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I have had similar issues like this in IE7 and 8. They were always to do with the CSS. I found the problem by just adding the video to a very simple page with nothing but mediaelement and slowly added my own CSS until I found the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I ended up switching to videojs now, but if that doesn't work I will test your process.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the CSS as Paul suggested, it turns out a "position: relative" style on a  wrapping the video area was the cause.